# Printf function does not works with char

Tags: c, char, printf, scanf

I got a problem, because the printf fuction does not show any result when I try to debug the code. What I am doing wrong? Can someone tell me? I tried to put the buffor, to make a space before the %s in scanf, but it does not work.

```c
struct worker {
    char name[50];
};

struct worker tab[1000];
int worker_count=0;
int c = getchar();
if (c == 'D') {
    ++worker_count;
    printf("Put the name:");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf_s(" %s", &tab[worker_count].name, 1);
    printf("Imie: %s\n",tab[worker_count].name);
}
system("pause");
```

Comment: If you want to print a single character, you should use `%c` in your printf()

Comment: I will change names to English as soon as possible, sorry. Okay, I have changed %s in printf and scanf functions and the result is single, random sign, do someone knows what's wrong with that?

Comment: @PiotrZajkowski: Please provide a [mre] (which includes a function `main`).

Comment: Generally, it is a good idea to check the return value of `scanf` and `scanf_s`, in order to verify that all arguments were successfully matched. Also, when using `scanf_s`, you probably want to install a [constraint handler](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/set_constraint_handler_s).

Comment: It works fine with scanf, I have lost like 2 hour for such an easy thing, thanks for that, appreciate.